# Rails app does not load a specific JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, assets

I currently try to port [this template](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/creative/) from [startbootstrap.com](http://startbootstrap.com) into my rails app. Most of it already works but the navigation bar does not change its color while scrolling.

The different colors are achieved by the creative.js file. I put this file under assets/javascript and included as in my application.js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.easing.min
//= require jquery.fittext
//= require wow.min
//= require creative
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

I inspected the assets with the Chrome Developer Tools and the creative.js file does not appear there. Since the other javascript files appear in the asset folder the asset pipeline seems to be working. 
What do I have to change so that the creative.js file appears in my assets too?

Comment: Just a quick check -- I assume you restarted the server after the change and cleaned up the browser cache, right?

Comment: Yes, I did this several times already.

Comment: Are you sure the creative js file is actually present in the asset pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my project where I tried to incorporate Bootstrap's creative theme. 
The issue for me was that creative.js was not included at the right position (if you notice in the [original theme](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-creative/) the JS script calls are made at the end of the HTML file, after all the class and id declarations).

Your order of inclusion inside `application.js` is correct =>

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap.min
//= require jquery.easing.min
//= require jquery.fittext
//= require wow.min
//= require creative
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

However, there is a good chance that `application.js` is not included at the right spot. Ensure that you are including the files after the below code segment has ended =>

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
```

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the coffee file with the same name.
In your case `creative.coffee`

It worked for me!